# How to get specific tpr from a sequence of fpr in R?

Tags: r, roc

I want to get the true positive rates at specified false positive rates, says, at fpr = 0, 0.002, 0.01, .... is there an easy way to do that? I tried

`performance <- performance(rocr,"tpr","fpr") 
 fpr=performance@x.values[[1]]
 tpr=performance@y.values[[1]]`
 
which I can get all the fpr and tpr. How shall I proceed from here? Many thanks!

Comment: something like `tpr[which(fpr == yourfpr)]` ?

Comment: Could you provide a complete example? (with the package and data)

Comment: I used package ROCR then  'rocr <- prediction(probabilities,actual); performance <- performance(rocr, "tpr", "fpr" )'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Doing something like [TC Zhang suggests in comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54642823/how-to-get-specific-tpr-from-a-sequence-of-fpr-in-r#comment96079392_54642823) is not going to work:

```
tpr[which(fpr == yourfpr)]
```

This is because, although it is called a "curve", a ROC curve really is a set of discrete points, and the probability that your target FPR exactly matches one in the ROC curve is low.

Therefore you need to do a bit of interpolation to get the TPR at given FPR points. Fortunately the pROC package does that for you (dislaimer: I am the author of pROC). So let's say you have the following ROC curve:

```
library(pROC)
data(aSAH)
myroc <- roc(aSAH$outcome, aSAH$wfns)
```

First, you need to convert your FPR rates to specificity that pROC understands:

```
target.fpr <- c(0, 0.002, 0.01, 0.2, 0.1, 0.2, 1)
target.sp <- 1 - target.fpr
```

Then you use the [`coords`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/pROC/topics/coords) function:

```
coords(myroc, x = target.sp, input = "specificity", ret = c("se", "sp"))
```

This takes the target specificities as input, and returns them along with the matching sensitivities, which are equal to the True Positive Rates or TPR you're interested in. To get the TPR as a vector, do:

```
tpr <- coords(myroc, x = target.sp, input = "specificity", ret = "se")[1,]
```

Comment: I will accept answer by @Calimo as it demonstrate me how to use different package to solve my problem.